# Repeat all columns and data for all the resulting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have below table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[Price] [int] NOT NULL,
[Qty] [int] NOT NULL)
```

With a select query, I can get the below:

```
Name      Price    Qty
NIKE       600     1
ADIDAS     500     2
Skechers   400     5
FILA       250    10
```

But I want a result like below.

```
Name    Price    Qty  Name    Price    Qty  Name      Price    Qty  Name    Price    Qty
NIKE     600     1    ADIDAS   500     2    Skechers   400     5    FILA      250    10
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't. A column's name should be unique, and it won't be here. Seems like an XY problem.

Comment: You want  [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: As Larmu said you first have to add a tag Name1, Name2, Name3... Price1, Price2, Price3 before you can do the pivot

Comment: why do you want a result like that? It's not very clear to read. But if you really do, it's probably something you should do in an application presentation layer rather than SQL.

Comment: @Larnu @Juan will this work 

`SELECT *
FROM 
(
 SELECT
 ProductID,
 Name,
 Price,
 Qty
 FROM  Product GS
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
 MAX(ProductID)
 FOR Name in (Name, Price, Qty)
) AS pivotTable`

Comment: Easiest way to find out is test; but it won't be dynamic. Like I said, this is clearly an XY problem.

Comment: @Larnu I tried few difference ways but I have to specify the result in PIVOT which make no sense. I dont know what are the data I have in the table. What do you mean by XY problem?

Comment: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. But I dont know how to explain it. That's why I added a result set in the question. What's the thing you don't understand here. I really need your help on this.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza This is the PIVOT I used. But for that I should know the result set.

`SELECT *
FROM 
(
 SELECT
 ID,
 Name,
 Price,
 Qty
 FROM  #Product GS
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
 MAX(ID)
 FOR Name in (NIKE, ADIDAS, Skechers, FILA)
) AS pivotTable`

How can I add tag names to columns to make it repeatable? Not same as alias I think

Comment: I understand what you want, but my point is that you really *don't* want to do what you're asking here; it's a really bad design choice. Hence why what I want to know is the *real* problem you want to solve.

Comment: @Larnu I just need to extract some data to excel sheet. This is the way my client needed. He insists that he needs all the product details like above

Comment: Then arguably the real problem is to convince the client that there is a nicer way to use their data... :-). I cannot imagine how they find a layout like that to be helpful

Comment: @ADyson client has some different idea in his mind. He does not want to repeat company data along with product detail. He might use some filters in excel. So my job is give the things that he wants.

Comment: @user2837480 Sure. But this layout won't help him with either of those things, as far as I can see. Sometimes your job is also to tell the client when what they want is pointless/useless/incorrect/illogical/nonsensical/just not the best solution, and show them a better way. Usually, if your idea genuinely is better, and you persuade them politely, and they are not arrogant idiots, then they will agree. After all, they are paying you for your expertise. For that reason, my clients very rarely get exactly what they originally asked for, but they're also very rarely dissatisfied :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is ugly, and I still think this is an XY Problem, but it does the job you asked for...:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Create sample table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL, --Do you REALLY need 2GB to store the NAME of a product? What name is going to be 2,000,000,000 character in length..?
[Price] [int] NOT NULL,
[Qty] [int] NOT NULL)
GO
--Insert sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.Product (Name,
                     Price,
                     Qty)
VALUES('NIKE    ',600, 1),
      ('ADIDAS  ',500, 2),
      ('Skechers',400, 5),
      ('FILA    ',250,10);
GO
--Solution
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                         N'       MAX(CASE ID WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(ID,'''') + N' THEN [Name] END) AS [Name],' + @CRLF +
                         N'       MAX(CASE ID WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(ID,'''') + N' THEN Price END) AS Price,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       MAX(CASE ID WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(ID,'''') + N' THEN Qty END) AS Qty'
                  FROM dbo.Product
                  ORDER BY ID ASC
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,10,N'') + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.Product;';

PRINT @SQL; --Your Best Friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
--Clean up
--DROP TABLE dbo.Product;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to make this query a dynamic one..? Sorry im not really good at SQL

Comment: If it's always going to be the 4 rows, then no. if it's a variable number, yes. Youre description implies the latter, so yes it need to be dynamic. This is, again, why I suggest this is an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks for the support. You clearly one of the bests ;)